# What are meanings of fields in /proc/net/dev?

Tags: linux, tcp

The Linux file /proc/net/dev reads like this:

```
[me@host ~]$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
```

What do fields *drop* and *errs* mean?

Are some *errs* packets also counted in the *drop* packets?

Why is a packet considered *errs* , is it because that it suffers from checksum error?

Why is a packet dropped? Is it because that the system has no enough buffer of because there is some burst on the NIC?

Do the two fields take packets that are destined to another host (e.g. when the NIC is working in promiscuous mode) into consider?

Comment: do these number reset at some point ? Are these lifetime numbers ?

Answer (score 23):

You can have a look at `net/core/dev.c` in the source tree to see what it means:

```
seq_printf(seq, "%6s:%8lu %7lu %4lu %4lu %4lu %5lu %10lu %9lu "
       "%8lu %7lu %4lu %4lu %4lu %5lu %7lu %10lu\n",
       dev->name,
       stats->rx_bytes,
       stats->rx_packets,
       stats->rx_errors,
       stats->rx_dropped + stats->rx_missed_errors,
       stats->rx_fifo_errors,
       stats->rx_length_errors + stats->rx_over_errors +
        stats->rx_crc_errors + stats->rx_frame_errors,
       stats->rx_compressed,
       stats->multicast,
       stats->tx_bytes,
       stats->tx_packets,
       stats->tx_errors,
       stats->tx_dropped,
       stats->tx_fifo_errors,
       stats->collisions,
       stats->tx_carrier_errors + stats->tx_aborted_errors +
        stats->tx_window_errors + stats->tx_heartbeat_errors,
       stats->tx_compressed);
```

So:

- receive errors means any kind of invalid packet, e.g. invalid length or invalid checksum
- transmit errors are

  - carrier errors
  - aborted errors
  - window errors
  - heartbeat errors
    (whatever they all mean)

And yes, I think drops means when the device dropped a packet because it ran out of buffer space.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between receive drops and transmit drops?

Comment: I would guess there is a buffer for each, and it drops packets when the buffer is full.  Receive drops would be when the system or application are too slow to handle incoming packets (e.g. system is overloaded, or the application is processing packets slower than they are arriving).  Transmit drops would be when the network card or network are too slow to handle outgoing packets.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have guessed something on similar lines. Do you know of any source that can provide certainty about this?

Comment: do these number reset at some point ? Are these lifetime numbers ?

Comment: In recent kernels this is in `net/core/net-procfs.c` https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/core/net-procfs.c

Answer (score 15):

According to http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html, the meanings of each of the columns are:

> **bytes** The total number of bytes of data transmitted or received by the interface.
>
> **packets** The total number of packets of data transmitted or received by the interface.
>
> **errs** The total number of transmit or receive errors detected by the device
>   driver.
>
> **drop** The total number of packets dropped by the device driver.
>
> **fifo** The number of FIFO buffer errors.
>
> **frame** The number of packet framing errors.
>
> **colls** The number of collisions detected on the interface.
>
> **compressed** The number of compressed packets transmitted or received by the device
>   driver. (This appears to be unused in the 2.2.15 kernel.)
>
> **carrier** The number of carrier losses detected by the device driver.
>
> **multicast** The number of multicast frames transmitted or received by the device
>   driver.

Comment: Link points to O'Reiley site now. [This](http://web.archive.org/web/20180522173537/http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html) could replacement could be

Answer (score 0):

Since noone has answered for almost six months, I feel free to speculate:

I don't think the *errs* and *drops* overlap.  I also think that *errs* are checksum or other bad data in a **received** packet (i.e. not enough data to constitute a whole packet).  Further, I believe *drops* only apply to **outgoing** packages - how would the system know about dropped packages somewhere else?

Comment: You're right, they don't seem to overlap.  _drops_ can apply to both.  For example, if an application on this computer is sending data out at 1 Gb/s and you've got a 10 Mb/s NIC.  You can also guess it can happen just because _drops_ appears on both the Receive and Transmit sections of the output.

Answer (score 0):

### Never thought I'd see the day where I might have some input.

Until I get my laptop up and running, I use a variety of apps on Android. I happened to be using the Terrible Termux, and came across this (I'll let the pros do the interpreting):

```
ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    inet 192.168.87.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.87.255
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 3000  (UNSPEC)
```

(I think that's the right format?)